# Thumbnail generation for uploaded video in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using **ffmpegthumbnailer** gem for generating thumbnail image for the uploaded video in my rails app. Then I am getting the following error.

```
VideoFailed to thumbnail with ffmpegthumbnailer. Check ffmpegthumbnailer install and verify video is not corrupt. Original error: No such file or directory - ffmpegthumbnailer
```

I have installed ffmpegthumbnailer in my ubuntu local system which fixed my issue. My question is

Is there any gem in rails which generates thumbnail image for video without installing anything additionally in my system

Comment: Every gem used some inbuilt libraries to perform the operation, so you need to install dependent libraries to perform  the desired operation. Like to use `carrierwave`, you have to install `Imagemagick` and `MiniMagick` these in your system.

Comment: I am using Rmagick for uploading image but I haven't installed any libraries additionally. Just included the gem carrierwave and rmagick in gem file

Comment: Sorry. I found imagemagick is already installed in my System. Thank you @SourabhUpadhyay. But is my question's answer is 'No'

Comment: that was an just example to let you know that few dependencies you need to install those haven't per-installed.

Comment: My production server is using centOS and I am not able to find a proper way to install ffmpegthumbaniler in it. I have successfully installed it in my local linux system.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to install ffmpeg and ffmpegthumbnailer. These two machine dependent libraries is responsible to take a snapshot of the video.

FFmpegthumbnailer is a lightweight video thumbnailer that can be used by file managers to create thumbnails for your video files. The thumbnailer uses ffmpeg to decode frames from the video files, so supported videoformats depend on the configuration flags of ffmpeg.

Any gem uses ffmpeg and ffmpegthumbnailer internally to capture the image of your video.

`Processing by Api::V1::SomeController#upload_image as */*                                                           Parameters: {"image_or_video"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000000569f5f0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20190404-12316-vu14aq.mp4>, @original_filename="image_or_video.mp4", @content_type="video/mp4", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image_or_video\"; filename=\"image_or_video.mp4\"\r\nContent-Type: video/mp4\r\n">, "auth_token"=>"pyuG3UEthHzzJHFCLEV6"}

  Running....ffmpegthumbnailer -i /mnt/p/dir1/dir2/tmp/1554378249-12316-0001-1852/video_thumb_large/image_or_video.mp4 -o /mnt/p/dir1/dir2/tmp/1554378249-12316-0001-1852/video_thumb_large/tmpfile.png -c png -q 10 -s 400 -t 1%     Success!`

See docs: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ffmpegthumbnailer.1.html#synopsis

For ffmpegthumbnailer installation, Run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpegthumbnailer
```

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-18-04/ (For ffmpeg installation)

Gem for video thumbnail

```
 gem 'carrierwave-video-thumbnailer',github: '23shortstop/carrierwave-video-thumbnailer'
```

See docs: https://github.com/evrone/carrierwave-video-thumbnailer